# Matrix of linear map can always be written as diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$, $W$ be $n$, $m$ dimensional vector spaces respectively. If $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $W$, show that there are bases B and C such that the matrix $A = \left(a_{ij}\right)$ of T with respect to those bases satisfies $$a_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 &  \text{if $i = j \leq \min\{n,m\}$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
How should I approach this problem? I've tried some small examples but I haven't been able to gain any insight.

Comment: This is obviously false if $T = 0$ and $V, W$ are nontrivial.  I think the statement should be: ... there are bases $B$ and $C$ and nonnegative integer $r \le \min \{ n, m \}$ such that the matrix ... satisfies $a_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1, & \mathrm{if~}i = j \le r \\ 0, & \mathrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Comment: If $T$ is of maximal rank, this is true; in any case, this is called Smith Normal Form, and over a field you might as well demand the nonzero elements on the diagonal to be all one. If not maximal rank, all that would change is that the entry would be $1$ when $i = j \leq r,$ where $r$ is the rank of $T.$   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Comment: Hint: the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors. What does this mean for the columns that have zeros along the diagonal (or the trailing columns)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at the proof of the rank-nullity theorem $\dim V = \dim \ker(T) + \dim \operatorname{im}(T)$ (or depending on your notation, $\dim V = \dim N(T) + \dim R(T)$).  That might give you some inspiration that will lead you to the bases $B$ and $C$ that you need.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

Take a basis $C'$ of the subspace $TV \subset W$. Take $B'$ a subset of $V$ that maps to $C'$ by $T$. It turns out that $\langle B' \rangle \oplus \operatorname{Ker} T = V$, so if $B''$ is a basis of $\operatorname{Ker} T$ then $B\colon = B'\cup B''$ will be a basis of $V$. Complete also $C'$ to a basis $C$ of $W$. You got your bases now.